# Oracle XE on AWS License for Test Instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oracle-xe

Can I install Oracle XE on EC2 instance for internal Test Server? I need to setup one web application for internal testing before I deploy to Production RDS instance.

Does license permit to use it on cloud for internal testing? I have already purchased Oracle RDS instance for production.

Here is what I understand is that - it can be used as production but limitation will enforced at XE Database that it will not use more than 1 CPU and 11GB of user data.

***Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size host machine with any number of CPUs (one database per machine), but XE will store up to 11GB of user data, use up to 1GB of memory, and use one CPU on the host machine.***

Comment: That's not a technical question.  Call up your Oracle rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Oracle 11 XE, you can use other versions and use Oracle Technology Network License Agreement.
You can download the following versions Oracle 18c, 12.2.0.1.0 - Standard Edition 2 and Enterprise Edition, 12.1.0.2.0 - Enterprise Edition, 12.1.0.2.0 - Standard Edition (SE2), 11.2.0.1.0 Standard Edition, Standard Edition One, and Enterprise Edition and use it only for the purpose of developing, testing, prototyping, and demonstrating without violating the license.

[Oracle Technology Network License Agreement](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html)

> License Rights and Restrictions  Oracle grants You a nonexclusive,
>   nontransferable, limited license to internally use the Programs,
>   subject to the restrictions stated in this Agreement, **only for the
>   purpose of developing, testing, prototyping, and demonstrating** Your
>   application and only as long as Your application has not been used for
>   any data processing, business, commercial, or production purposes, and
>   not for any other purpose. You may allow Your Contractor(s) to use the
>   Programs, provided they are acting on Your behalf to exercise license
>   rights granted in this Agreement and further provided that You are
>   responsible for their compliance with this Agreement in such use. You
>   will have a written agreement with Your Contractor(s) that strictly
>   limits their right to use the Programs and that otherwise protects
>   Oracle’s intellectual property rights to the same extent as this
>   Agreement. You may make copies of the Programs to the extent
>   reasonably necessary to exercise the license rights granted in this
>   Agreement. **You may make one copy of the Programs for backup purposes**.

Update 1
A feature of the installation in the cloud is the Amazon.
Before installation, you must make a swap.

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=20M count=100
 mkswap /swapfile
 swapon /swapfile
 swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file    2047996 243300  -1
```